# fetch column name of affected rows in mysql pdo?

Tags: php, mysql

I am running an update query using PDO. I am updating only four rows but I do not know the names of columns. I can easily get the count of rows using rowCount() but I also want to fetch the column name as well. Is there any function in PDO which will help for the same? If not then please tell me the other method for fetching this.

Comment: Read [getColumnMeta](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php)

Answer (score -2):

You don't need PDO, you can get the names with MySQL:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table`
```

Hope it helps